# How do I load the ngMeta Angular module with Browserify?

Tags: angularjs, browserify

I made the switch to browserify, and so far it's working out great for me, except that I am struggling to require the ngMeta module.

I installed the module through NPM, and it is present in the node-modules folder.

I tried `require('ng-meta');` and I get the error: 
`Error: Cannot find module 'ng-meta/ngMeta' from '/Users/traaidmark/Sites/crio/the-cradle/mobisite/4--www/assets/js/scripts'`

I have tried several variations of ngMeta and ng-meta. I suspect that the ng-meta module is not a proper NPM module, and therefore I will need to require it differently, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: To provide more info: I was able to simply `require('angular-ui-router');` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ngMeta](https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ngMeta) does not have support for Browserify yet. I created an issue [here](https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ngMeta/issues/5)